# Confused about Javascript hierarchy behavior (sample code given)

Tags: javascript

I am still relatively new to Javascript, and have been trying to wrap my head around how a particular library is managing such clean types and naming convention.

The library in question is *Telerik's* **Kendo UI**, and specifically I am curious how they are achieving something that reminds me of C# namespaces. For instance... there is a type called an *ObservableArray*, which can be accessed through **kendo.ui.ObservableArray**.

I dug into the source code and am really confused about what is going on. I have omitted a lot of the code for proprietary reasons, but the general closure shouldn't be an issue. I was wondering if someone could help me to grasp how they are achieving some of this...

```
(function ($, evil, undefined) {
    var kendo = window.kendo = window.kendo || { cultures: {} },
        extend = $.extend,
        each = $.each; // more code omitted

    function Class() { }

    Class.extend = function (proto) {
        // most of this code omitted
        return subclass;
    };
    // more code omitted
})(jQuery, eval); // this line is really confusing me
```

Particularly, what has me lost beyond belief is that second line. Where they are declaring a variable (*kendo*) equal to a variable defined on *window*. I have searched high and low for hours and hours and cannot for the life of me figure out where this is first happening. I have been unable to reproduce the same behavior in my own code.

I have figured out that the **extend** function serves as a way to pair up an object with an existing object, and selectively attach it like an accessible member. But that **window.kendo** thing, it is driving me crazy.

Comment: It's just an alias, creating a local variable which points to `window.kendo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so complicated. Take this, for example:

```
var a, b, c;
a = b = c = 100;
```

Parentheses might help:

```
a = (b = (c = 100));
```

`c = 100` is actually an expression. It assigns `100` to `c` and then evaluates to `100`. So that progresses to:

```
a = (b = 100);
```

then it assigns `100` to `b` and further simplifies:

```
a = 100
```

And it finally also assigns `100` to `a`.

---

So when you have the following:

```
var kendo = window.kendo = window.kendo || { cultures: {} }
```

First it assigns the result of `window.kendo || {cultures: {} }` to `window.kendo`. Then it assigns that same result to the local variable `kendo`.

---

The final trick is what `window.kendo || {cultures: {} }` does, exactly. `a || b` evaluates to `a` if `a` is true, or `b` if `a` is false:

```
10 || 20; //evaluates to 10
undefined || 20; //evaluates to 20
undefined || null; //evaluates to null
```

So, if `window.kendo` is not defined yet, `window.kendo || {cultures: {} }` evaluates to `{cultures: {} }`. Otherwise, it evaluates to whatever `window.kendo` is, already.

This is a nifty way of specifying defaults, for example:

```
> function logit(s, label) {
    label = label || "nolabel";
    console.log(label + ": " + s);
}
> logit("Hey there")
nolabel: Hey there
> logit("Hey there", "Fooman")
Fooman: Hey there
```

Comment: Yes! I see! That makes sense. This works perfectly, thank you so much! It was driving me nuts, but it was very simple.

Answer (score 0):

`window.kendo` is a way to get a global variable named `kendo`.

```
kendo = window.kendo = window.kendo || { cultures: {} }
```

This will set the value of both the local `kendo` and the global `kendo` to either the value of the global if it exists, or if the global does not exist it will set it equal to that object literal.

Comment: It's also not the only way to reference a global variable. If you write "myGlobal = 5", when myGlobal is not already a local variable, that variable is then accessible anywhere as "myglobal", or "window.myGlobal". Setting "window.myGlobal" is often preferrable when one wants to be explicit about it.